# Uniqueness of for loop

Tags: c++, c

How does the for loop function is implemented so that it can accept `;` as parameter separator rather than `,` which is trivial in normal functions.

Comment: [Sharing your research helps everyone](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6559/why-is-research-important). Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. Also see [ask]

Comment: It would be helpful if you gave some basic facts, like why you feel the need for ";" rather than ","

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `for` loop is not a function, the `for_each` is http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each which takes `,` as parameter separator.

`for` is a statement, according to the C++ standard §6.5.3.

You can look at a `for` as a set of actions being performed, like this: `for(initialization; condition; expression)` at which point they really aren't different parameters, but different statements.

Comment: So to actually answer the question: A `for` loop is special-cased by the parser, and is not parsed like an ordinary function.

Comment: @TommyA an important bit to consider in this is that one can use the expression separator (`,`) to do more complex things (primarily in initialization and incrementing): `for(i = 0, j = 0; i < 10; i++, j += 2) { ... }`.

Comment: @MichaelT that is true, in which case it works as an expression separator, rather than a parameter separator, as you write :)

Comment: Its important to realize that for is described as `for ( {<expression>}? ; {<expression>}? ; {<expression>}? ) <statement>` in the grammars - expressions, not parameters.